# How to see the clocksource in a linux without sysfs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, sysfs

I know that for a common Linux OS, the clocksource can be viewed by the command
`cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource`

However I have a Linux system with kernel version 2.6.27.7, and there is no /sys/ folder inside. Then how can I see which clocksource is used?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: I have used the combination of dmesg and egrep but I cannot find message about clocksource.

Comment: There is no way except an additional module which will deliver the information to you somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in /usr/src/linux-2.6.27.7-9/drivers/clocksource. If you haven't defined a totally different 'tree', of course... (don't forget to sudo when you run 'find'!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I find the place, and it is a folder. Inside my `/usr/src/linux-2.6.27.7/drivers/clocksource` folder, there are several .o and .c files like  `acpi_pm.o`, `acpi_pm.c` and a `Makefile`. 

Is the folder a place to load the clocksource as loading a module? 

For I cannot understand what should I do next to see the currently used time clocksource yet, could you give me further assistance?